# Combine different columns pattern of string to a new column in R

Tags: r, regex, string

I have a data frame like this and i would like to create a new column where I collect only SYMBOL from the other two columns if it exists.

```
   V1                 V2
   -------------------------------------
   SYMBOL=GABRD       SYMBOL_SOURCE=HGNC
   FLAGS=cds_end_NF   SYMBOL=GABRD
   SYMBOL=MASP2       SYMBOL_SOURCE=HGNC
   FLAGS=cds_start_NF SYMBOL=GABRD
   SYMBOL=GABRD       SYMBOL_SOURCE=HGNC
   FLAGS=cds_start_NF SYMBOL=GABRD
```

So the result will contain in a new column only with the Symbols based on pattern "SYMBOL="

```
V3
-----
GABRD   
GABRD   
MASP2   
GABRD   
GABRD   
GABRD
```

Comment: can it be assumed that:  1) There will always be a `SYMBOL=` on each row?  2) There will only ever be one `SYMBOL=` on each row?

Comment: usually if in one row of the column there is SYMBOL= GENE in the other column there is something else like SYMBOL_SOURCE=HGNC but always one of the two columns contain the SYMBOL=

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach using `dplyr`. We `mutate()` [`across()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html) `V1` and `V2` to find the rows starting with `SYMBOL=` and then [`coalesce()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/coalesce.html) those into a new column.

```r
dat |>
    mutate(across(V1:V2, \(x) if_else(
        grepl("^SYMBOL=", x), x, NA_character_
    ), .names = "{.col}_symbol")) |>
    mutate(
        V3 = sub("^SYMBOL=", "", coalesce(V1_symbol, V2_symbol))
    ) |>
    select(-V1_symbol, -V2_symbol)
  

#                   V1                 V2    V3
# 1       SYMBOL=GABRD SYMBOL_SOURCE=HGNC GABRD
# 2   FLAGS=cds_end_NF       SYMBOL=GABRD GABRD
# 3       SYMBOL=MASP2 SYMBOL_SOURCE=HGNC MASP2
# 4 FLAGS=cds_start_NF       SYMBOL=GABRD GABRD
# 5       SYMBOL=GABRD SYMBOL_SOURCE=HGNC GABRD
# 6 FLAGS=cds_start_NF       SYMBOL=GABRD GABRD
```

Note: if you have two rows which both begin with `"SYMBOL="` then `coalesce()` will return the first one that is not `NA` (i.e. `V1`).

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate(V3 = coalesce(
    ifelse((str_detect(.$V1, "^SYMBOL=")), str_remove_all(.$V1, "SYMBOL="), NA), 
    ifelse((str_detect(.$V2, "^SYMBOL=")), str_remove_all(.$V2, "SYMBOL="), NA)
    )
  )
  
                  V1                 V2    V3
1       SYMBOL=GABRD SYMBOL_SOURCE=HGNC GABRD
2   FLAGS=cds_end_NF       SYMBOL=GABRD GABRD
3       SYMBOL=MASP2 SYMBOL_SOURCE=HGNC MASP2
4 FLAGS=cds_start_NF       SYMBOL=GABRD GABRD
5       SYMBOL=GABRD SYMBOL_SOURCE=HGNC GABRD
6 FLAGS=cds_start_NF       SYMBOL=GABRD GABRD
```

Used data:

```
data.frame(V1= 
             c(
               "SYMBOL=GABRD",       
               "FLAGS=cds_end_NF",   
               "SYMBOL=MASP2",       
               "FLAGS=cds_start_NF", 
               "SYMBOL=GABRD",      
               "FLAGS=cds_start_NF" 
             ),
           V2= 
             c(
               "SYMBOL_SOURCE=HGNC",
               "SYMBOL=GABRD",
               "SYMBOL_SOURCE=HGNC",
               "SYMBOL=GABRD",
               "SYMBOL_SOURCE=HGNC",
               "SYMBOL=GABRD"
             )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Test data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  V1 = c("SYMBOL=GABRD",       
         "FLAGS=cds_end_NF",   
         "SYMBOL=MASP2",       
         "FLAGS=cds_start_NF", 
         "SYMBOL=GABRD",       
         "FLAGS=cds_start_NF"),
  V2 = c("SYMBOL_SOURCE=HGNC",
         "SYMBOL=GABRD",
         "SYMBOL_SOURCE=HGNC",
         "SYMBOL=GABRD",
         "SYMBOL_SOURCE=HGNC",
         "SYMBOL=GABRD")
)
```

Base R solution:

```
df$V3 = apply(df, 1, FUN = \(x) ifelse(grepl("SYMBOL=", x[1]), 
                                       gsub("SYMBOL=", "", x[1]), 
                                       gsub("SYMBOL=", "", x[2])))
```

Here:

```
> df
                  V1                 V2    V3
1       SYMBOL=GABRD SYMBOL_SOURCE=HGNC GABRD
2   FLAGS=cds_end_NF       SYMBOL=GABRD GABRD
3       SYMBOL=MASP2 SYMBOL_SOURCE=HGNC MASP2
4 FLAGS=cds_start_NF       SYMBOL=GABRD GABRD
5       SYMBOL=GABRD SYMBOL_SOURCE=HGNC GABRD
6 FLAGS=cds_start_NF       SYMBOL=GABRD GABRD
```

Edit:
assumption: - v1 and v2 are the first two columns in df.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple and short base R solution:

```
> df$V3 <- with(df, gsub(".*SYMBOL\\s?=\\s*(\\w+).*", "\\1" , paste(V1, V2)))
> df
                  V1                 V2    V3
1       SYMBOL=GABRD SYMBOL_SOURCE=HGNC GABRD
2   FLAGS=cds_end_NF       SYMBOL=GABRD GABRD
3       SYMBOL=MASP2 SYMBOL_SOURCE=HGNC MASP2
4 FLAGS=cds_start_NF       SYMBOL=GABRD GABRD
5       SYMBOL=GABRD SYMBOL_SOURCE=HGNC GABRD
6 FLAGS=cds_start_NF       SYMBOL=GABRD GABRD
```